# Editing existing pre-created menus in PHP

Tags: php, menus, themes, scripts

Here's my pickle. I'm using a script to automatically create a fully pledged WordPress site. In this process new pages, etc are created automatically. I now need a way to add the newly created page(s) to an existing menu on site from the script (this menu was created automatically by the theme I us and is pre-filled with links to some demo pages).

The script has full access to all WordPress functions, but I cannot use hooks (since this is all run before the site is even up). Is there a way to pull an existing menu into the script and change it's contents?

**EDIT**:
In regards to the possible duplicate, the other article provides a way to create a new menu. I'm in the market for a way to recover and edit an existing menu to change it's layout and add items to it. :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: this can be done with a plugin. have you ever create a plugin ? http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: I've created quite a few plugins in my life, it's kinda what I do for living XD, but thing is, I can't use a plugin in this case because this code gets executed BEFORE the site is live, so the plugin won't even be live yet. :/

Comment: if the script initialize WordPress, it can activate a plugin too, no ?

Comment: Yes...it can in fact do that, but...the problem is the pages the script creates are being made before plugin code can be called, and besides that the projects spec won't allow for the use of another plugin. I will look into it if I can find no other way of doing it and my thinking is, what ever code I was going to use in the plugin, might as well be in the script, doesn't matter as the result would be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically add a Navigation menu and menu items](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/programmatically-add-a-navigation-menu-and-menu-items)

Comment: @RRikesh: I believe that covers creating a new menu from scratch which isn't entirely what I'm doing. I was looking for a way to edit an existing menu, but I think through much trial and error that I've come up with something, if it works, I will post the results of my findings here to help others who have the same issue.

Comment: Can't you use WP-CLI for the project or you have some project restrictions?

Comment: @denis.stoyanov I'm limited to using only the single script file for the project, so right now everything's in that one file, but I'm manage to find a solution that I will post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem by going over the documentation again and again, looking through source files and just generally running the same section of code over and over to scrutinize the output.

**This is the solution I came up with, which works just perfectly for my needs**:

```
//  Get a list of all the menus that are part of the site
    $menu_list = wp_get_nav_menus();
    $menu_id = -1;
//  Iterate over all the menus...
    foreach( $menu_list as $menu ) {
    //  ...and find the one you want...
        if( $menu->name === 'Main Menu' ) {
        //  ...and get it's ID.
            $menu_id = $menu->term_id;
        }
    }

//  Delete everything except the Home entry
    $menu_content = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Main Menu' );
    foreach( $menu_content as $menu_item ) {
        if($menu_item->title !== 'Home') {
            wp_delete_post($menu_item->ID);
        }
    }

   /* OTHER CODE USED FOR BUILDING PAGES, ETC CODE */

   /**
    *   Menu building code
    *
    *   @since 0.4.0pre1
    */
    $menu_data = array(
                        'menu-item-title' => ( $menu_text !== '' ) ? wp_strip_all_tags( $menu_text ) : wp_strip_all_tags( $page_title ),
                        'menu-item-object' => 'page',
                        'menu-item-parent-id' => ( $parent !== '' || $parent !== 'none' ) ? intval( $parent ) : 0,
                        'menu-item-position'  => ( $menu_position !== '' ) ? ( intval( $menu_position ) === 1 ? 2 : intval( $menu_position ) ): 2,
                        'menu-item-object-id' => $post_id,
                        'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
                        'menu-item-status' => 'publish'
                     );

//  Add this menu item to the existing nav menu if it is set to visible
    if( intval( $menu_visible ) !== false ) {
        wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, 0, $menu_data );
    }
```

Feel free to suggest any improvements to the code, or any other suggestions :)